# Multiple Problems on XUbuntu after Python upgrade, deinstalling default Python. How can I fix them with out going back/reseting the system?

Tags: xubuntu, python, xfce

I recently installed XUbuntu LTS 22.04 on an old Laptop, all went well with the setup but today I wanted to set up the latest stable version of Python (3.12.1) and I installed it no problem, but then I removed the preinstalled Python 3.10 (using Synaptic) and this all sorts caused problems:

- The start menu button is a warning sign
- the Bluethooth symbol is a warning sign
- the symbol for the settings are warning signs
- the symbol for log off is a warning sign
- the symbol for log screen is a warning sign
- there is a one-way symbol in my taskbar telling me that the machine had problems installing update packages.
  And that are just the problems I can see at a glance. Trying to go into settings anyway the mashine brought on an error message it is missing xfce4-settings-managers as a child process. I tried to reinstall it with sudo apt install xfce4-settings but in doing so it would also reinstalled Python 3.10, trying to use the apturl root as described in the Wiki also brought me to a point where the computer wanted to reinstall Python 3.10. Is there anyway to avoid this and just instruct the machine to just use Python 3.12 for everything? Now if it is not possible it is no biggy, but still slightly annoying that I either need to
  keep the old Python version and use the long name with the version I want to use or forgo the newest version.

My task bar:

[image: my task bar]

Comment: "*Is there anyway to avoid this and just instruct the machine to just use Python 3.12 for everything?*" Your problems were caused by doing exactly that. There are several ways to avoid it...after you have repaired your system.

Comment: Many Ubuntu tools on Desktop systems rely on `python3`, and only work *reliably* with the default version the system came with. Do not change that version if you wish to continue using the desktop; base tools will work (`wget` to download files, `dpkg` to install etc) but higher-level tools (inc. parts of `apt`) may not work until python3 is restored. Failure to operate is the better choice (*corruption of data can also occur, though unlikely*). If you want a higher *default* version of python3 use a later Ubuntu release. You can have multiple python3 versions too, but DO NOT change default.